# How to subset text from a column in R

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset certain tree species from my existing data frame just so that I can analyze those specific species.
For example, I am trying to extract Quercus species from the column 'species' but still have all of the information associated with them. I have attached the head of my data frame so you can have a better idea what I'm talking about. I also have about 800 rows if that information is necessary. [seedlings_1995](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6232.jpg)

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `subset(seedlings_1995, species == "Quercus")` should work. Or, if you're using dplyr, `seedlings_1995 %>% filter(species == "Quercus")`.

Comment: Is the species "Quercus", or is that word part of the species name? There's no example of it in your data sample. (Also, it's best not to provide data as an image. You can provide it in a machine readable format using `dput`)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work; you can further access it with the variable and if you don't want it, just skip using variable x:

```
x<-seedlings_1995[seedlings_1995$species=="Quercus",]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions using `dplyr`, the second one also uses also `stringr`. This code works with some sample data similar to yours.

```
df<-data.frame(Sp = c(rep(paste("Quercus",seq(1,10,1),sep=" "),3),
                      rep(paste("Acer",seq(1,10,1),sep=" "),3)),
           Info1 = rnorm(60,100,20),
           Info2 = rnorm(60,50,5))
```

If you are interested in selecting only certain species, the first option will be more useful.

```
library(dplyr)
#The species you are interested in analysing
species_of_interest<-c("Quercus 1", "Quercus 2", "Quercus 10")
#Then filter and save it in df1 object
df1<-df %>%
  filter(Sp %in% species_of_interest)
```

However, if you are interested in analysing all the species of one particular genus, like *Quercus*, this approach might be more helpful:

```
#select every species containing the word "Quercus" (which can be interpreted as all 
#the species of the genus Quercus).

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1<-df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Sp, "Quercus"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone who answered,

Thanks so much for the advice. I ended up using this line of code:

quercus_sd_95<-new.five.seedling[grep("Quercus",new.five.seedling$species),]

and got exactly what I needed. I tried using the subset function but it was looking for just the word "Quercus" instead of any values that had "Quercus" in their species name. By using grep I was able to extract all values that had "Quercus" in the species name. I know there are a million ways to accomplish this in R, but this is just one way that worked for me.

Thanks again.

Again, thank you all so much!